# GridLayout not showing on my device

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, grid-layout

This is my `xml` code:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainGrid"
        android:columnCount="2"
        android:rowCount="3"
        android:alignmentMode="alignMargins"
        android:columnOrderPreserved="false"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="14dp"
        >
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:src="@drawable/icona_monumenti"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:text="Me"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <!-- Column 2 -->
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:src="@drawable/icona_piatti_tipici"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:text="Family"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


        <!-- Row 2 -->

        <!-- Column 1 -->
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <ImageView
                    android:src="@drawable/icona_storia"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp" />
                <TextView
                    android:text="Lovely"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            >
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <ImageView
                    android:src="@drawable/icona_informazioni"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp" />
                <TextView
                    android:text="Team"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    </GridLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

In the preview of my xml file, the `GridLayout` is visible, but when I run the application, on my phone the `GridLayout` is not visible.

gradle:
    *implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'*

The code don't give me error or other things, and the same the stack trace

This is the image of my layout:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is the need of `GridLayout` here?

You can use nested `LinearLayout` this is the blue-print of that:

```
                 LinearLayout
                  (Vertical)
                      |
           -------------------------
          |                         |
     LinearLayout              LinearLayout
     (Horizontal)              (Horizontal)
          |                         |
    -------------             -------------
   |             |           |             |
CardView      CardView    CardView      CardView
```

And the code is:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    andriod:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        andriod:orientation="horizontal">

        <!--Row 1-->
        <!--Column 1-->
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:src="@drawable/icona_monumenti"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:text="Me"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <!-- Column 2 -->
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:src="@drawable/icona_piatti_tipici"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:text="Family"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        andriod:orientation="horizontal">

        <!-- Row 2 -->

        <!-- Column 1 -->
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <ImageView
                    android:src="@drawable/icona_storia"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp" />
                <TextView
                    android:text="Lovely"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <!-- Column 2 -->
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <ImageView
                    android:src="@drawable/icona_informazioni"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp" />
                <TextView
                    android:text="Team"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: ok, i found the error: in the cardview the android:layout_height must be match_parent, now it worked completely.

Answer (score -1):

Add a LinearLayout enclosing each element of the GridLayout
Making the width of the LinearLayout to "0dp".
Setting the width of the inner element to "match_parent"